Seleniumbase page_source error, I can't get the html code
I run the newest seleniumbase. I need the uc mode for the login and etc.
I got this only after the newest chromium released (130).

driver = Driver(uc_cdp=True, incognito=True)'


driver.get("https://****.com/")'

But I dont get the full page (it is visible also) for driver.page_souce I got only this:
<html><head></head><body><script src="audio.js"></script><audio></audio></body></html>
How to fix to get the full page? Thank you!

There were changes in Chrome 130 that required changes to SeleniumBase UC Mode.
(Details here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/issues/3236)
Upgrade to SeleniumBase 4.32.5 (or newer if available), and retry your script.
